# Scrolling problem with various widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a specific view in which I have more than 1 "big" widget on screen. The idea is to show both a GridView (shrinkwrapped) with a maximum of 4 cards of close events, and a ListView (also shrinkwrapped) that can hold up to a couple dozens of music bands.

Both things could be on separated views, but it's a requirement to show these short grid + list in the home view. It also looks better, IMO. But Flutter is causing me problems with the scrolling.

Take a look at how it currently looks:

[image]

As for now, I'm capable of showing both the GridView and ListView, but the scroll works really, really bad. As for now, both widgets are wrapped inside a SingleChildScrollView, which I guess it's not a good solution since it doesn't have a single child. It is able to work if I hold the finger in a part of that parent widget (just like the title, or the black background), but not if I hold it on any of the widgets (gridview or scrollview).

My aim is to get the scroll functionality delegated to the parent widget, so wherever I put my finger, I can scroll the whole view and not only scroll a child view, as it currently happens.

This is my HomePage code:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text(widget.title),
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30)),
              Text(
                '¡Bienvenido a Sonorio!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25)),
              EventsList(key: new Key('test')),
              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.amber[600],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[500],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[100],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

The EventsList widget is just a GridView that has shrinkWrap:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(
        future: new EventsService().getEventsForCoords(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Event>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(children: [
              Text('Eventos musicales en tu zona: ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      shadows: [
                        Shadow(
                            blurRadius: 2,
                            color: Colors.indigo[300],
                            offset: Offset.fromDirection(1, 1))
                      ],
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                      color: Colors.indigo[200],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8)),
              GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: generateProximityEventCards(snapshot.data)),
            ]);
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
```

How can I get this working, or at least, delegate child widgets scroll functionality, to the parent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the requirements I see that, **you don't want child scroll, else you just want the scroll to happen on the layout, that is for `ParentWidget`**

There are certain changes I would suggest to make that happen after looking at your code:

- Use `Column()` in place of `ListView()`
- Use [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html), it disables the scrolling for the `Widget`

There are certain things, which I have changed in the code, so just look at the end result, and make the amendments.

- Your `GridView` uses my dummy `Container()` Widget in place of your widget `generateProximityEventCards(snapshot.data))`
- Did not use `FutureBuilder`, cos, I am using the static data. So, just used `Column()` part to show you the end result

Let us jump into the code directly

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30)),
              Text(
                '¡Bienvenido a Sonorio!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25)),
              EventsList(),
              // Used column with padding for ListView
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.amber[600],
                      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.amber[500],
                      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
    );
  }
}

// cusomt eventlist widget, you can make the changes eventually
class EventsList extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget get myWidget => Container(
    height: 50.0,
    width: 50.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0, left: 18.0, bottom: 18.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
    )
  );
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text('Eventos musicales en tu zona: ',
          style: TextStyle(
              shadows: [
                Shadow(
                    blurRadius: 2,
                    color: Colors.indigo[300],
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(1, 1))
              ],
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              color: Colors.indigo[200],
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8)),
      GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //diables the scrolling
          children: [
            // my widget which I created
            myWidget,
            myWidget,
            myWidget,
            myWidget
          ]
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: End Reuslt Gif]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! The core thing about your post is the "physics" property, which I didn't know, and the solution to use a Column instead of a ListView in the end. That actually fixed the problem! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Great to see that response coming from your side @Zerok. Glad to see that thing working out for you. We thrive for learning every day. And we learnt something today, so a great start :D